# Removing special type from list that contains multiple types C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, subclass, base-class

The problem I have is that I want to remove a certain item from my list that contains 2 different type. Whatever I try I just get errors and that I can use types, if I create a new instance of that class it won't delete the old. I'm really stuck here, I have no idea on what I should do.

```
private List<Toys> toys = new List<Toys>();
toys.Add(new Ball("red"));
toys.Add(new MouseToy("gray"));

public abstract class Toys {}    
public class Ball : Toys {}
public class MouseToy : Toys {}

//how do i remove only one of the types?
//beacuse this does not work witch is one of many things i tried
    foreach(var toy in toys){
       if (toy.GetType == Ball){
          toys.Remove(toy)
       }
     }
```

That's pretty much the code I use for the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do just:

```
toys = toys.Where(toy=>!(toy is Ball)).ToList();
```

As mentioned @Sefe in comments (thanks): you could  use do it even simple and better with

```
List<MouseToy> mouseToys =  toys.OfType<MouseToy>().ToList();
```

If it's ok for you that your new collection will be `List<MouseToy>` not `List<Toys>` . And that won't work if you will get a third class `CatToy` and you will still want to get all items, but not of `Ball` class

Comment: Is it that easy? i mean i dont think i really understand what it does tho. what value "typ" "thing"  does toys get ?

Comment: oh wait i think i understand, i removes the ball object from the list and then makes it to a list again only containing the rest.

Comment: @JohannesBjärehall  Yes, you creates a new list where  are only those objects, that are not Ball.

Comment: Why would you use `Where` and not `OfType`? Sure you can enter the house through the window, but why not use the door?

Comment: @Sefe The true answer is: I have forgotten about it and took the most obvoius and simple (for me) answer, sure you are right and if we want to have only MouseToys better is to use OfType. OP  wanted to have not MouseToys but "not Balls", it is not the same if would have a third class CatToy.  I will update answer,  because your point is right and for this case is nicer to use OfType. And OfType<MouseToy> will return List<MouseToy> not List of toys

Comment: You're right that for exclusion of a type you would need `Where`, because `OfType` wouldn't cover that. In the given example `OfType` is enough though.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues with your solution:

1. You are modifying the list you are iterating with `foreach`. That will cause an `InvalidOperationException`.
2. `.GetType == Ball` does not work like this. Use `is` instead.

Try this:

```
foreach(var toy in toys.ToArray()){
   if (toy is Ball){
      toys.Remove(toy);
   }
}
```

You can also use LINQ:

```
foreach(var toy in toys.OfType<Ball>().ToArray()){
  toys.Remove(toy);
}
```

Comment: man, i defiantly learnt something, it was really easy when i look at it now haha, well tanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove items from a list while iterating over that same list. You can either use a reverse `for` loop (i.e. loop descending):

```
for (int i = toys.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (toys[i] is Ball)
    {
        toys.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

...or you can use one of the methods defined in the `System.Linq` namespace. Maksim Simkin shows how to use the `Where` method; you could also use the [OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) methods:

```
toys = toys.Except(toys.OfType<Ball>())
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it seems so obvious when i see your code.